# python blackjack aces break my code calculations

Tags: python, blackjack

I am coding a blackjack game. I append all cards including royals and aces and 2 through 10. What I'm having trouble with is the aces. My problem is being able to calculate all cards before calculating A, to clarify this, I mean I want to calculate ALL cards before ANY aces in a list so I can see if the total is greater then 11, if so then just add 1 for every ace if not, add 11. My code thus far:

```
import random

def dealhand(): #This function appends 2 cards to the deck and converts royals and aces to letters.
    player_hand = []
    for card in range(0,2):
        card = random.randint(1,13)
        if card == 1:
            card = "A"
        if card == 11:
            card = "J"
        if card == 12:
            card = "Q"
        if card == 13:
            card = "K"
        player_hand.append(card)
    return player_hand

#this function sums the given cards to the user
def sumHand(list):
    total = 0
    for card in list:
        card = str(card)
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card== "K":
            total+=10
            continue
        elif card == "2" or card == "3" or card == "4" or card == "5" or card == "6" or card == "7" or card == "8" or card == "9" or card == "10":
            total += int(card)
        elif card == "A":
            if total<11:
                total+=11
            else:
                total+=1
    return total
```

Comment: Seems like you need to separate your list of cards in 2;  not-'a' and 'a' elements, then operate on one then the other

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? As an aside: `def sumHand(list):` you really should not shadow python names/keywords/... by using them for variables.

Comment: my assignment asks that I use the variable name list even though I thought it was also a bit weird

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest total += 1, aces += 1 then at the end, add 10 if needed for each ace.

A few pointers on asking a question: don't post the dealhand function, as that is completely irrelevant. Post the input, output and expected output

```
def sumHand(hand):
    ...

hand = ['A', 'K', 'Q']
expected 21
actual 31
```

Here is my suggested fix (minimal change for this particular issue)

```
def sumHand(hand):
    total = 0
    aces = 0
    for card in hand:
        card = str(card)
        if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card== "K":
            total+=10
            continue
        elif card == "2" or card == "3" or card == "4" or card == "5" or card == "6" or card == "7" or card == "8" or card == "9" or card == "10":
            total += int(card)
        elif card == "A":
            total += 1
            aces += 1
    for _ in range(aces):
        if total <= 11:
            total += 10
    return total
```

I changed "list" to "hand" because that's hiding a builtin class's name, but otherwise didn't mess with it. I would suggest adding a (unit tested) function to get a card's value. Maybe a dict which serves as a name-value map. You could simplify some of the conditions with the "in" operator. It's weird that handle ints by converting them to string and then back to int. But none of that directly relates to the issue of counting aces.